# Starter not engaging motor

Tags: motorcycle, starter, wiring, kawasaki

I have a 1986 Kawasaki bayou 300 that the starter is not engaging the motor. I put a brand new starter on and didn’t fix it. Also put on a new starter solenoid and still didn’t fix it. I checked every wire possible an they are good. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What you mean by "starter not engaging the motor" is not clear. What happens when you turn on the key? What happens when you push the start button? Do you hear anything? Does the starter spin? Does the motor turn over?

Comment: If you've already replaced every aspect of the starter motor and no change then the problem must be with what the starter motor engages with